# How to convert a for loop into a mathematical function/expression?

Tags: for-loop, math, mathematical-optimization

I have some code in the form of a for loop, which is fine for programming, but not if I want to publish that algorithm in a paper or article. Therefore, I'd like to write that algorithm in the form of a mathematical expression.

The algorithm essentially consists in returning the iteration that verifies the condition inside the for loop

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
  if(min_x + i*db <= theta <= min_x + (i+1)*db)
    break;
  else if(min_x > theta)
    break;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the second inequality in your second line is `<=` rather than `<`? If the line were `if(min_x + i*db <= theta < min_x + (i+1)*db)` there would be an easier expression.

Comment: for this matter, there's no problem in being < instead of <=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an expression that works if the second inequality in your second line is `<` rather than `<=`. In other words, the expression below fits if your line were

```
if(min_x + i*db <= theta < min_x + (i+1)*db)
```

My expression also assumes that `db` is positive. If it is allowed to be zero (yielding a divide-by-zero error) or negative, things get more weird.

```
i = min(n, int(max(theta - min_x, 0) / db))
```

The `int` could be shown by one of the regular symbols for the greatest integer function, such as regular square brackets or square brackets without the upper horizontal lines.

NOTE: A hat-tip to @aka.nice for an improvement to handle the case when the `for` loop exits normally rather than with a `break`.

Comment: Isn't a `min(n,...` missing? Also `floor` might work for negative db...

Comment: @aka.nice: You are right about the `min`: I will add that. The negative `db` is more complicated due to the inequalities in the code. I considered `floor` but decided not to test that, since zero `db` is definitely different between the code and my expression.